# How to characterize the category Group, and define exactness therein?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, homological-algebra

I am currently trying to come up with a definition of an exact sequence of groups which uses only category theoretic definitions. That is I am trying to come up with a list of criteria for an arbitrary category which is sufficient to construct exact sequences and prove their properties and which is satisfied by the category group. Obviously one can develop exact sequences in an abelian category but Group is not abelian.

I observe that Group has all kernels and cokernels, all equalizers and coequalizers, a zero object, and all epimorphisms are cokernels. I am trying to use only these hypotheses to define exact sequences and derive their properties but I am stuck.

I can define $\textrm{im }f = \ker(\textrm{coker }f)$ and $\textrm{coim }f = \textrm{coker }(\ker f)$. Since all epimorphisms are cokernels $\textrm{coker }(\ker f)$ satisfies the definition of the coimage given by wikipedia. Further, the coimage produces an epic-monic factorization of $f$ because Group contains all coequalizers (this argument is from $\textit{Categories for the Working Mathematician}$ pg 193). The problem is that because Group is not normal, I cannot show that $\textrm{im }f = \ker(\textrm{coker }f)$ satisfies the universal property in the definition of the image, nor can I show that $\textrm{im }f = \textrm{coim }f$.

To define exactness I say that $A \buildrel a\over\longrightarrow B \buildrel b\over\longrightarrow C$ is exact iff $\ker b = \ker(\textrm{coker }a)$ which I can show is equivalent to saying  $\textrm{coker }a = \textrm{coker }(\ker b)$. This has the benefit of not requiring equalizers, coequalizers, normality, or conormality because I am not requiring the kernel of the cokernel or the cokernel of the kernel to satisfy the definitions of the image or coimage respectively.

My immediate goal is to use only my definition of exactness and the properties I have observed about Group to prove that in every short exact sequence, $$0 \longrightarrow A \buildrel a\over\longrightarrow B \buildrel b\over\longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$$  $a$ is monic and $b$ is epic.

I have proven that $a$ is monic: Group is conormal with all coequalizers so $\textrm{coker }(\ker a) = \textrm{coim }a$ and yields an epic-monic factorization of $a$. Further, $\textrm{coker }0 = 1_A = \textrm{coker }(\ker a)$ by my definition of exactness so $a$ factors through $1_B$-monic and thus $a$ is monic.

I am stuck at proving $b$ is epic. If I could show $\ker(\textrm{coker }a) = \textrm{coker }(\ker a) = \textrm{coim }a$ then I could dualize my previous argument and use the dual definition of exactness (ker = ker coker) to get the result. However I don't see how to establish this equality using the existence of equalizers, coequalizers, and conormality.

I observe that any monomorphism can be factored through a normal monomorphism (since any subgroup is included in its normal closure) and that this factoring has a universal property by the minimality of the normal closure, but I can't quite see how to incorporate this into Mac Lane's argument fruitfully.

Could someone give me some help?

Comment: See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category.

Comment: I think the problem here is that, defining $\operatorname{Im} f$ by $\operatorname{ker}(\operatorname{coker} f)$ you get something bigger than what you'd want : if I'm not mostaken, in $Group$, the cokernel is the quotient of the codomain by the normal closure of $\operatorname{Im}f$, which is usually bigger than $\operatorname{Im} f$

Comment: Note that $\ker(\operatorname{coker}(a))=\operatorname{coker}(\ker(a))$ cannot be true in general, since one is a mono and the other an epi.

Comment: yes, what I mean't was that coker(ker $a$) produces an epic-monic factorization in Group (because group is conormal with coequalizers) which would be a triple (epic, Object, monic). What I'd like to establish is that the sub-pair (Object, monic) coincides with ker(coker $a$).

Answer (score 0):

Max's comment is correct : with your definition of exactness, $b$ need not be epic. You have that
$$\operatorname{coker} (b)=\operatorname{coker} (\ker(0))=\operatorname{coker} (1_C)=0,$$
but that doesn't mean that $b$ is epic; for example, if $C$ is a simple group and $b:B\to C$ is any non-zero morphism, then the cokernel of $b$ must $0$ (because its kernel is a normal subgroup of $C$ containing the image of $b$).

If you want to define a short exact sequence, you need to have good notions of image and kernel. Probably the minimum to ask is for the category to have a cokernel-monomorphism factorization system; then every extremal epimorphism is a cokernel, and if moreover you require the category to be finitely complete and the factorization system to be pullback-stable (as in the category of groups), then you obtain a regular category where regular epimorphisms coincide with cokernels, which is sometimes called a normal category.

Comment: Your observation about simple groups is a good point. However I'm struggling a little with your third paragraph. Since the cokernel of the kernel satisfies the universal property in the definition of the coimage, and Group has all coequalizers, the coimage gives us a cokernel-monic factorization system. To define exactness I can either say that the kernel of the outgoing arrow must be equal to the monic in the factorization of the incoming arrow, or the cokernel of the incoming arrow must be equal to the cokernel in the factorization of the outgoing arrow.

Comment: Obviously I chose to try the latter, since I can prove saying coker = coker ker is equivalent to ker = ker coker. I see the validity of Max's comment but there seems something not quite right about defining exactness as the coimage of the incoming arrow being equal to the kernel of the outgoing arrow. (By which I mean, the coimage produces a triple (epic, Object, monic)  in Group and I am requiring that the sub-pair (Object, monic) is the kernel of the outgoing arrow.)

Comment: @CRSmath I don't understand what you mean. Exactness of $A\stackrel{a}\rightarrow B\stackrel{b}\rightarrow C$ in the usual sense is precisely the condition that the pair (object, monic) given by the factorisation of $a$ is a kernel of $c$; what do you find "not quite right" with that?

Comment: Well usually factorization of $a$ is usually given by the image not the coimage in most definitions, and I have no way to prove that the image is equal to the coimage, or for that matter exists. I can show im = ker if and only if coim = coker, so it makes sense to try and define exactness as coim = coker. You seem to be suggesting defining it as $coim = ker$. I see that is both possible and would give the properties I am asking, so there isn't a formal reason not to do it, but it seems quite different from the standard definitions of exactness I have seen.